# New leaves with holes on my spathiphyllum

Tags: plant-care

for a while now new leaves on my Spathiphyllum are being born with some holes and signs of "burn" on the edges (see some pictures at the end of the post). At first I found old leaves started having these "burn" signs on the edges, but after doing some reading it seemed to be from improper watering and has improved since. But the issue with the new leaves persists.

[The plant from this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/what-causes-deformed-spathiphyllum-leaves) seems to have a similar problem and there's a suggestion about moving it to a place with better light. The place where my plant is at right now gets plenty of daylight, but not directly. I can try moving it but it would probably mean moving it to a place where it would receive a couple of hours of strong, direct sunlight, so I wanted to ask first to see if my specific case looks similar.

Pictures:

Small hole in a leaf, it didn't get worse as time passed
[image: Leaf 1]

One of the worst ones. Again, it was born that way but didn't get worse with time.

[image: Leaf 2]

A new one as it was being born, you can see it already shows issues:

[image: Leaf 3-1]

And this is the same leaf, a couple of days later:

[image: Leaf 3-2]

Answer (score 1):

Some pest of some sort is damaging the leaves when they are small - I can see what look like white flecks on various leaves, but not clearly enough to decide what they are, so examine the plant closely, preferably using a magnifying glass, inspecting all stems, the underside of leaves, and in the central part of the base where new leaves arise from. Also look for any signs of fine webbing in case its spider mite. Depending what you find, you will likely need to spray with something - an insecticide or neem oil spray. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/peace-lilies-bugs-35777.html

Comment: Agree with this. I've had a spathis develop leaves with brown, dry fringes when I'd left it in direct sun too many hours of the day, but this damage does seem pest-related.